# SQL query looking for improvements

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have written this query to get all the information need for my task. But due to my lack of knowledge in SQL, the query is not that good.
The query results in a very long execution time.
The database, that is used to run the query, has over a million rows for just this year alone, so I really hope it can be optimized.

```html
CREATE VIEW vNew_Test_View AS
SELECT a.point_id, a.lab_station_id, a.point_name, b.timestamp, c.timezone, b.value, 
  LAG(b.value,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY b.point_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS val_prev
FROM PointList a, 
     PointData b,
     Lab_Timezone c
WHERE a.point_id = b.point_id 
  AND a.lab_station_id = c.lab_station_id 
  AND b.timestamp > '01/01/2020'
```

Optimally I would like some pointers on what to improve, maybe how or where to look.

The database is set up in a way, where i need the lab_station_id to know what the timezone is.

The goal is this:

[image: Example results]

Comment: How do you expect people to be able help you if you don't tell us what you're trying to do **exactly** ? I have no idea what you're query is supposed to do.

Comment: Why is that outdated comma join style still being used?  Please learn proper [JOIN syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Hey, for future reference is **really** hard for a lot of us to follow screen captures of your data. You are **MUCH** more likely to get a good answer if you copy/paste the date into the question, and then use the code formatting tool to keep the line breaks and spacing.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide the LAG function in your output?

Answer (score 0):

The first improvement I'd make is getting rid of those old janky `a,b where` joins. That syntax has been obsolete for 25 years now. Instead, use the real `a inner join b on` syntax.

The next thing I'd do is use a better date literal. For date-only values (no time component), the best option is the ISO8601 unseparated format. So `01/01/2020` becomes `20200101`.

We end up with this:

```
SELECT a.point_id, a.lab_station_id, a.point_name, b.timestamp, c.timezone, b.value, 
  LAG(b.value,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY b.point_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS val_prev
FROM PointList a
INNER JOIN PointList b ON b.point_id = a.point_id 
INNER JOIN PointList c ON c.lab_station_id = a.lab_station_id
WHERE b.timestamp > '20200101'
```

However, this won't do much if anything for the long execution time, and there's probably not much you can do in SQL query alone that will help; that is, I don't see any obvious performance issues here. Instead, to gain any meaningful improvement you should look at what **indexes** are defined on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have performance issues you need to look at the explain plan.

This article explains how you can do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15

In general you want to have indices on the columns you join on and the ones you filter in order to improve performance. If you can offer more info on the explain plan I could advise further.